# PHP: Unable to echo certain array values from json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, echo

Have JSON as $json

I convert it to an array using:

```
$myarray = json_decode($json, true);
```

print_r($myarray) gives this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
( [ProjectId] => 2765297 [ProjectName] => Acme Example) 
[1] => Array
( [ProjectId] => 4526847 [ProjectName] => Smiths Example)
)
```

When I try to use foreach like this:

```
foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
echo $result[ProjectName] . ' Project ID:' . $result[ProjectID];
}
```

I get the ProjectName but not the ProjectID.

When I look as the original JSON ($json), the ProjectID appears to be unquoted like an integer.

```
[
   {
        "ProjectId":2765297,
        "ProjectName":"Acme Example"
    },
    {
        "ProjectId":4526847,
        "ProjectName":"Smiths Example"
    }
]
```

When I try to convert to a string or run checks to see if it is an integer, it is ether blank or null.

Comment: 1) Use quotes for your keys 2) `ProjectID` != `ProjectId`

Comment: In you json you have ProjectId but you are trying to access ProjectID (case sensitive), maybe is that, and I recommend you to put the array key between apostrphes like $result["ProjectID"]

Comment: Rizier123, it is overwhelmingly frustrating that I do not heed Occam's razor. It was my lack of attention to case that was the problem. Thanks for your quick response.